# Firefox push notifications - send data via curl

Tags: firefox, curl, push-notification, payload, service-worker

`Mozilla` `Firefox` [since 44 version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/44.0/releasenotes/) ([unlike 49 version of `Google` `Chrome`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web)) supports `push-notifications` with payload. One can see examples [here](https://serviceworke.rs/push-get-payload.html).

`Firefox` [demo project](https://people.mozilla.org/~ewong2/push-notification-test/), which is mentioned on [`Firefox` wiki page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Push_Notifications), generates `curl` run parameters as:

```
curl -I -X POST --header "ttl: 60" "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/gAAAAABW4ccaidtFYOP2m56-XiY_NSKDXV1QiJ-4cpZG5BF-W7FjWE17SDt-h-b4b4VJamuvL30OcI9msyM1bupE9YHrwQZH4D7Uh2YS8cE_Tpvnvm3CgpBjblH58sE78HQjjbahB5NG4CkkKLj13gz0eB9mOAVGfcM3qo4Z61M5fn_6HZqLvCg="
```

Now how to add payload to `curl`, which will be delivered to registered `service-worker`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't simple because the payload needs to be encrypted.

If you're just interested in testing the functionality out, I recommend trying [this page](https://jrconlin.github.io/WebPushDataTestPage/). At the end, if you follow the steps, it prints the `curl` command to send a notification.

If you want to learn more about how to encrypt the payload, there's the standard [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-webpush-encryption-01).

If you want to use a Node.js library that hides the complexity to send the payload, there's the [web-push library](https://github.com/marco-c/web-push).

Assuming:

- `p256dh key = BPdbyNlxaH6zreGrZfHWtct8xVR9g1LjOagGsdyxllxT-BsWC5zFBlp4AsD4uXZ3kAA6zfqQPLoLxEklSI2muoU`
- `salt = FD9bsatP7pGf6qeO_XVu_Q`
- `local key = BMGAejiMWatMYFfEdV-YIZpbMeW9N41tav6DW_S7eNRP6In9wwKs-XpKGGkxZUI3-bPti5HBBLY1E8uVRlsF6FE`

An example command would be:

```
echo -ne "\x12\xdb\xd8\xc5\xcc\x92\x0f\xf2\xa5\x9d\x8c\xca\xea\x58\x13\xf6\xbd\x9a\x14\xa5\xca\x6f\xa0\xb3\x6c\x73\x32\x4a\x4e\x03\x55\x8c\x11\x62\x45\x8d" > encrypted.data; curl -v -X POST https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/push/v1/SUBSCRIPTION_ID_HERE -H "encryption-key: keyid=p256dh;dh=BMGAejiMWatMYFfEdV-YIZpbMeW9N41tav6DW_S7eNRP6In9wwKs-XpKGGkxZUI3-bPti5HBBLY1E8uVRlsF6FE" -H "encryption: keyid=p256dh;salt=FD9bsatP7pGf6qeO_XVu_Q" -H "content-encoding: aesgcm128" -H "TTL: 60" --data-binary @encrypted.data
```

Comment: Imagine encryption task is solved. What's parameter for `curl`?

Comment: I've added it to the reply. Obviously it won't work for you because you'll have different keys than mine and a different endpoint URL.

Comment: what is the use of local key? can you tell us?

Comment: you do not need an encryption if no payload